# when to combining multiple imports into a single file

Tags: es6-modules

As I understand then combine multiple export statement into a single file is considered a good practice iff source file comes under the same directory

so

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject, Subject, ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';
```

can be re-written to

```
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject, Subject, ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';
```

But what If I have to import only one module than which is preferred way? using a complete file or a specific one.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

OR

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

does that cost anything extra?

ts v 2.3.4

angular v 4.4.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

This is the efficient way to import a single module, because you are providing the exact path to only fetch the required module.

Whereas in this case,

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

It will import a lot of unnecessary stuff from the rxjs library that will increase the page load time and/or the code base.

Comment: Thanks. so instead of `import { Observable, BehaviorSubject, Subject, ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';` we have to include separate modules statement is also preferred?

Comment: Yeah, thats correct. Just to save time and code ,we import all in a single statement.

Comment: your solution in not valid for rxjs5 , t is mentioned [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) 
> deep imports: Can no longer deep import top-level types such as rxjs/Observable, rxjs/Subject, rxjs/ReplaySubject, et al. All imports should be done directly from rxjs, for example: import  { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';